# Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A.$ Is it true that if $x^{\perp}$ is invariant under $A,$ then $A$ is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb C,$ and let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A.$ If $x^{\perp}$ is invariant under A, is it true that $A$ is normal?

Here is my idea.

> Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ such that $Ax = \lambda x.$ Let $y \in x^{\perp}.$ Then, we have that $\overline{\lambda} y \in x^{\perp}$ and $A(\overline{\lambda} y) \in x^{\perp}$ so that $\left<A(\overline{\lambda}y),x\right>=\left<Ay,\lambda x\right>=\left<Ay,Ax\right>.$ So, $A$ is normal.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. $x=(1,0,0)^T$ is an eigenvector of $A=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0}$ and $x^\perp$ is $A$-invariant, but $A$ isn't normal.

The statement can be corrected by requiring that $x^\perp$ is $A$-invariant for *every* eigenvector $x$ of $A$. The corrected statement can be proved by mathematical induction on the size of $A$ or by constructing an orthogonal eigenbasis of $A$.

Comment: Very nicely done. +1

Comment: @user1551 I have to prove $A$ normal iff If $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $x^{\perp}$ is an invariant subspace of A. I demonstrated the direct implication and for the inverse we should to suppose that it is truth. I did that if                               
 $A\{x\}^{\perp}\subseteq \{x\}^{\perp}$ then $A^{*}\{x\}\subseteq \{x\}$. Hence $x$ is eigenvector of $A^{*}$. I don't know if this is truth. Thank you !

Comment: @Angelina Assuming that you have correctly shown that $A^\ast\{x\}\subseteq\{x\}$, then $x$ is indeed an eigenvector of $A^\ast$. But you still need to relate this fact to the conclusion (namely, $A$ is normal) that you want  to prove.

Comment: @user1551 then $A^{*}x=x$ then we can take eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ of $A$. So we have $Ax=x$ and $A^{*}x=x$ then $A$ is normal. But in general it is false as your example show.....That what i want to say ....

Comment: @user1551 in your example, we have $x^{\perp}=(0,a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{K}$, then $Ax^{\perp}=(0,b,0)$ and  it is not included in $x^{\perp}$, but if we take $a=b=0$ then its work, but $x^{\perp}=(0,0,0)$

Comment: @Angelina $x^\perp$ cannot be chosen at will. It is by definition the set of **all** vectors orthogonal to $x$. While any proper subset of $x^\perp$ is orthogonal to $x$, it isn't $x^\perp$ itself.